# My section won't show up

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website on the Chesapeake Bay but a `section` won't pop up, even though it has a `background-color`.

I'm not sure why, and this has never happened before while making websites. I'm using Atom to write my code, Notepad++ to compile it, and Chrome to display it.

My code:

```css
section {
  background-color: #75c776;
  width: 200;
  height: 400;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="title">The Cheasapeake Bay</h1>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

If some one could help me figure out what's wrong that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Run a linter on your CSS. Look at the styles in the style inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the units of your `width` and `height` properties:

```
width: 200px;
height: 400px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `px` in your CSS and there's a duplicate `-right`

New CSS

```
section {
  background-color: #75c776;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

New [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJLJgw)

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `height` needs to have units.

So you are missing the units in `width` and `height`

You can add `px`/`em`/`rem`/`vw`

```css
section {
  background-color: #75c776;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="title">The Cheasapeake Bay</h1>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<footer>

</footer>
```